# RN i18n issue on some iOS devices

Tags: android, ios, react-native, internationalization, right-to-left

I have developed an application using React Native (version 0.67.5). Initially, the app was released in French. Recently, I added support for the Arabic language, allowing the application to detect the device's language direction (RTL or LTR) upon first launch after installation. If the device's direction is RTL, the app starts with Arabic content and is forced to display in a right-to-left direction; conversely, it starts in LTR for devices in LTR direction.

Everything was functioning smoothly during testing without any issues. However, upon release to the stores, some users (not all) reported that their app started in Arabic, despite their devices being set to French or English and not Arabic. (Android users did not experience this issue.)

- For users with the existing app installed on their device and the device set to a language that isn't RTL, nothing should change.

Any insights on what might be causing this?